# Universally-generalized constraints

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass

Here's a pretty useful class:

```
class Foo f a where
  foo :: f a
```

It let's me make default values for lots of types. In fact, I might not even need to know what `a` is.

```
instance Foo Maybe a where
  foo = Nothing
```

Now I have a `Maybe a` for all `a`, and I can specialize it later.

```
specialize :: (forall a. f a) -> f Int
specialize x = x

fooMaybe :: Maybe Int
fooMaybe = specialize foo
```

Hmmm....that `fooMaybe` sure seems pretty specific. Let's see if I can use a context to generalize it:

```
fooAll :: (Foo f a) => f Int
fooAll = specialize foo
```

Oops! Guess not.

```
Foo.hs:18:21:
    Could not deduce (Foo * f a1) arising from a use of `foo'
    from the context (Foo * f a)
      bound by the type signature for fooAll :: Foo * f a => f Int
      at Foo.hs:17:11-28
```

So, my question is, how can I write `fooAll`, the generalized version of `fooMaybe`? Or, more generally, **how can I universally-generalize a typeclass constraint**?

Comment: You can't. Well, you can write `fooAll` if you make an `instance Foo f a where foo = undefined`. But that's not useful. You can not universally-quantify the constraint, you can't write `fooAll :: (forall a. Foo f a) => f Int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No good way in current Haskell right now. The [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package provides a type that might [do what you need](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/constraints/0.3.2/doc/html/Data-Constraint-Forall.html), although, I recently figured out how to break it.  Still probably your best bet, because if someone figures out how to do it right it will probably get updated

```
fooAll :: Forall (Foo f) => f Int
fooAll = specialize foo_f where
  foo_f :: forall a. f a
  foo_f = foo \\ (inst `trans` (Sub Dict) :: () :- Foo f a)
```